Jinja2: insert template variable immediately after {
I want to use Jinja2 to generate some SQL templates for Grafana.
The problem is that I want to pass name of Grafana variable as jinja template variable, and I need to do it immediately after { - inserting extra space in between is not an option:
WHERE '${{{ var }}:csv}' = ''

with expected output like
WHERE '${foo:csv}' = ''

Jinja fails to handle such template. What are the options to make it work?

you can escape the curly braces using block: {{ '{' }}
complete template that produces the expected output:
WHERE '${{ '{' }}{{ var }}:csv{{ '}' }}' = ''

prints:
WHERE '${foo:csv}' = ''

